# How to display picture Server side with Flask and OpenCV?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, opencv

I have a Flask server that shows a black image via OpenCV on a monitor. When arrives an HTTP request, it must show on the same window another image, which name arrives via parameter. After another request arrives on the endpoint "/destroy", a black images must be shown in the same window. I don' understand why this code doesn't work, do you have any suggestion? For not blocking the server, I need to use two different process in the endpoint, is this the correct way to use them?

```
#show black image before the server starts
image = cv2.imread("black.jpg",1)
screen = screeninfo.get_monitors()[1]
cv2.moveWindow("image", screen.x - 1, screen.y - 1)
cv2.imshow("image",image)
cv2.waitKey(1)

def imageShower(name):
    #get name parameter and shows image with that name
    image = cv2.imread(name+".jpg",1)
    cv2.imshow("image",image)
    cv2.waitKey(1)

def imageDestroyer():
    #return to black image
    image = cv2.imread("black.jpg",1)
    cv2.imshow("image",image)
    cv2.waitKey(1)

#at endpoint / start process that invokes imageShower()
@app.route('/')
def showImg():
    #store image name arrived via parameter
    name = request.args.get('name')
    #start process
    p = Process(target=imageShower(name))
    p.start()
    #return back to front-end 
    return "image showed"

#return black image on endpoint "/destroy"
@app.route('/destroy')
def destroy():
    #start process
    pd = Process(target=imageDestroyer)
    pd.start()
    #return back to front-end
    return "returned to black"
```

Comment: If you start a new process for each image action, you cannot expect them to cooperate using the same GUI window. A much simpler solution would probably be to write into an image file at a temporary location and run an image viewer separately, which automatically updates when the image file changes. Your server will be agnostic from the GUI, it will not be blocked by the GUI, and the whole operation will be more robust.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it! Have you got a code sample for that solution? So I will see how to load the image data from a file to another file.

Comment: I'm sure the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55279031/imutils-videostream-returns-nonetype-while-integrating-with-flask) will satisfy your query.